# How to get old tab switching behavior back in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs

At some point in Firefox's version history, switching tabs with ctrl+tab (right) and ctrl+shift+tab (left) got replaced by bringing up a selection of windows that the user can switch through, akin to Windows task switching with alt+tab.

How can I revert to the old style of switching tabs?

Comment: ? I have *never* seen a tab switcher like that. The selected answer also does not address the written question at all.

Comment: @DanielB: It does, as Firefox has one option for both features – activating "recently used order" also activates a visual tab switcher. This option was recently enabled by default for new profiles.

Comment: @grawity Ah I see. My Firefox profiles are all years old.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find and disable this option through *Preferences* → *General* → *Tabs*:

> **Tabs**
> [✔] Ctrl+Tab cycles through tabs in recently used order

Alternatively, you can set the following option in `about:config`:

`browser.ctrlTab.sortByRecentlyUsed` from `true` to `false`.

In older versions of Firefox this might be called `browser.ctrlTab.recentlyUsedOrder`.